# Cannot import name 'Image'

Tags: python, windows, image, image-processing

I'm trying to set up Python Imaging Library, but I'm getting an error.

```
>>> from imaging import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Image'
```

I've set up Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10. The over-arching goal here is to use an image processing library to analyze some images. I want to do things like count all non-white (or relatively white) pixels, note their positions and then compare with another similar image.

My directory:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `from PIL import Image`.

Comment: did you create file `imaging.py` with element `Image` inside ? `PIL` needs `from PIL import Image`

Comment: @ekhumoro that returns an error `No module name 'PIL'`

Comment: how did you install this `imaging` ? I don't have it in `pip`.

Comment: I just downloaded the zip file from Github

Comment: @whatwhatwhat. How did you install it? It should end up in `site-packages`. The import statement I gave will work if you install PIL properly.

Comment: then you have it incorrectly installed. `imaging` is not correct Python module folder. Add link to this GitHub. Maybe you should compile it - I see `C` files.

Comment: I downloaded it from [this link](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow), extracted the files, and then pasted the extracted files into a new folder in `C:\Users\dude\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat. Undo what you have done, and follow the instructions in the answer given by An Huy.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok, then how do I install `pip` to be used on Windows 10?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat. You don't need to install it (that's kind of the point of it).

Comment: this is the error I get when installing with `pip`:http://imgur.com/a/thEkD

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.

Comment: @ekhumoro should I just delete all the other modules I downloaded and pasted into `Lib` and do everything from `pip` now?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat. Yes, `pip` is the best thing to use if you can. You can remove what you pasted into `Lib`.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok sounds good, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You are importing a wrong module.
To install PIL I used

```
 pip install pillow
```

then you can use:

```
from PIL import Image
```

in your python code.

Comment: See my edited question - I put in the images of my directory. Assume that I've already downloaded, now I just need to know how to access it correctly.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: I think you should install by "pip" or "easy install". You did not install the module correctly.

Comment: Or you can try this one: 
put __ init __.py in the folder and call the file with

from imaging.PIL import Image

Answer (score 2):

you probably named your project as "PIL.py", change it :)

Comment: This might be insightful. But it needs more explanation why it could cause the problem and how the proposed solution could help.

Comment: This was the cause for me, thank you! The error was **"cannot import name 'Image' from partially initialized module 'PIL" (most likely due to a circular import)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved your file with the name "PIL.py" then it's a problem. In my case, I did the same thing that's why I was here to find the solution. When I changed the name of the file then it worked properly.

Actually, we can't save a python file with the exact same name as a python library which we are going to use in that file.